# How to calculate rows count from left join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am creating a google map service for different kinds of physical stores.Feedback of stores is stored in different table and other data is in different table.I created a query and it is returning perfect response to me but I need to calculte how many rows comes from feedback table so that i can count the percentage of feedback using following:

```
$totalfeed=ceil(($price+$value+$quality)/(3*count(rows count from feedback table)));
```

Here is my query

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT shoptitle,logopic,complocality, profileurl, lat, lng,feedprice,feedvalue,feedquality, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM marketplace_userdata LEFT JOIN marketplace_datafeedback ON marketplace_userdata.mageuserid=marketplace_datafeedback.proownerid HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Count() function to count the number of row of any query.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: i am using left join and want only count from feedback table result

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` condition against the first table and specify the table being counted.  You can replace the asterisk with a field from the marketplace_datafeedback table:

```
SELECT COUNT(marketplace_datafeedback.*), 
    shoptitle, logopic, complocality, profileurl, 
    lat, lng, feedprice, feedvalue, feedquality, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM marketplace_userdata 
LEFT JOIN marketplace_datafeedback 
ON marketplace_userdata.mageuserid = marketplace_datafeedback.proownerid 
GROUP BY marketplace_userdata.mageuserid
HAVING distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY distance
```